# What's wrong with my event observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, adminhtml, sales-order, custom-column-grid

I have done below code in my event observer to add custom column to my **sales order grid** and still do not display the column to my website's admin panel?

Here is my code:

**app/code/community/Mjsi/Orderprint/etc/config.xml**

```
<adminhtml>
 ---
  <events>
        <core_layout_block_create_after>
            <observers>
                <mjsi_orderprint_add_columns>
                    <class>Mjsi_Orderprint_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addColumnsToGrid</method>
                </mjsi_orderprint_add_columns>
            </observers>
        </core_layout_block_create_after>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <orderprint_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                    <class>Mjsi_Orderprint_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addMassAction</method>
                </orderprint_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
            <observers>
                <mjsi_orderprint>
                     <class>Mjsi_Orderprint_Model_Observer</class>
                     <method>adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore</method>
                </mjsi_orderprint>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
  <events>
 ---
</adminhtml>
```

**app/code/community/Mjsi/Orderprint/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Mjsi_Orderprint_Model_Observer
{
/** 
 * Add new column to orders grid
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function addColumnsToGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

    // Check whether the loaded block is the orders grid block
    if (!($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid)
        || $block->getNameInLayout() != 'sales_order.grid'
    ) {
        return $this;
    }

    // Add a new column rigth after the "Status" column
    $block->addColumnAfter('mjsi_orderprint', [
        'header' => $block->__('Printed'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'filter' => false,
        'renderer' =>'Mjsi_Orderprint_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Renderer_Printed',
        //'index' => 'coupon_rule_name',
    ], 'status');

    return $this;
}

public function addMassAction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

    if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
        && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
    {
        $block->addItem('massPrintSalesOrders_order', array(
            'label' => 'Print Sales Orders',
       'url' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('*/*/massPrintSalesOrders'),
        ));
    }
}

public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event) {

    $block = $event->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
        $block->addButton('order_print', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Orders'),
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $block->getUrl('*/*/print') . '\')',
        ));           
    }
}
}
```